# why does this sed command only fail from inside an expect script?

Tags: sed, expect

I am trying to use an expect script to edit a file on a remote machine.

The sed command fails when issued from within the expect script, yet it works when log on and run it manually (without expect script)

Here is what the command looks like inside the expect script

`send "sed -i -E 's/value=[0-9]+/value=9999/' target_file\r"`

The error that is returned

`invalid command name "0-9"`

Yet when I manually log on and run the command like this it works fine

`sed -i -E 's/value=[0-9]+/value=9999/' target_file`

Why does it fail when issued from the expect script but not otherwise, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Is `[` significant to `expect`?  You probably need to escape it.  (Sorry, my `expect` knowledge is a little rusty).

Comment: Not sure, but I will try escaping the square brackets, thanks

Comment: Expect uses Tcl and in Tcl `[ .. ]` is [command substitution](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.html#M11).

Comment: you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more familiar with shell syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets need to be escaped.
This works:

```
send "sed -i -E 's/value=\[0-9\]+/value=9999/' target_file\r"
```

Comment: Pedantically, only the opening bracket needs to be escaped.

Comment: Tcl uses `{braces}` like the shell uses single quotes, but the `\r` won't get interpreted as a carriage return: `send {sed -i -E 's/value=[0-9]+/value=9999/' target_file}; send \r`